# limit html characters per line in aspx

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Is there a way to configure visual studio to limit the characters on aspx page to a certain number of characters?

I tried setting the character limit on Formatting and Validation on aspx page. but that didnt work.

Comment: Are you talking about formatting the actual HTML, or styling the resulting text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReSharper for this (and MANY MANY other things).  ReSharper is (in my opinion) a required tool for anyone coding in C# as it makes your productivity sky rocket.  Take a look at this video to be convinced: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/presentation/codingSession/CodingSession.wmv

Comment: Do you get a commission for each copy of Resharper sold? :-p

Comment: i'm trying to limit the html markup not hte C# code. I already use ReSharper for that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools / Options / HTML

and enable Word Wrap. But you can not define character limit.

Comment: Yes, I tried the WordWrap but it only moves the characters to the next line if its an end tag.